# Can I use double past tense?

Tags: past-tense

Firstly I am not English native speaker so when speaking we might speak English but the sentence structure in daily use might be different, but since I got a message from my family this morning I have a question.

The message is

> "I brought food my mother bought me yesterday as today's breakfast."

I know you can use 2 different past tense (not in the same kind) but the one I gave you might not fall on this category.

So I have another question. If the above sentence is wrong. Can you help me make it right.

Comment: There is only one predicate in the sentence -- "brought".  The tenses of the verbs "brought" and "bought" are not inherently linked in any way.

Comment: There's no problem in grammar, but the syntax is both awkward and ambiguous. Try this: "I brought some food, which my mother had bought me yesterday for today's breakfast" OR "For today's breakfast I brought some food my mother had bought me yesterday."

Comment: Steve, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: "(that) my mother bought me yesterday" is a noun clause with its own structure. No issues at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your sentence the order of actions is different from their chronological order. 
The correct sentence should be like that:
"I brought some food, which my mother **had bought** me yesterday **for** today's breakfast"

I brought some food = the second action

mother had bought = the first action

In such case we use Past Perfect.
You could learn more about **Past Perfect**  in "English Grammar in Use" by R.Murphy, unit 15